# May I say "the use of English is acceptable?" on my website?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-usage

I'm a Taiwanese and I'm running a shopping website for my dad.

I want to add a sentence to express:

"If you want to contact us, but you don't speak Chinese, English is fine, then."

So, is "the use of English is acceptable?" good?  or any other better way?

thanks a lot. :)

Comment: It probably isn't necessary.  If the website is in English, then the customer will assume that the language of business will also be English.

Comment: No... the web is in Chinese. but sometimes we'll meet some customers from Japan or Vitnam or other countries that want to leave message to us.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have Japanese of Vietnamese then?

Comment: haha..no~I'm the only stuff can deal with this now. I can't read so many language. besides, the translate tool is not very correct for asian language. So, I hope foreign customers can use English if they can.

Comment: Note that ***His use of English is acceptable*** could mean either *It is **okay if** he uses English* (that's a valid choice of language) OR ***The way** he uses English is okay* (he uses English reasonably well). By the same token, there's a risk that *The use of English is acceptable* might be misinterpreted as implying *We use English reasonably well on this website*. So for the avoidance of confusion, consider ***Using** English is acceptable*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than saying "English is acceptable", you should say "We can accept (emails in) English (and Chinese)".

How much else you want to write depends on how chatty or formal your site wants to be.  You can write more "We are happy to communicate with you in English", for example.

Comment: wow~ thank you  thank you <3  wish you a nice day! ^^

Comment: After a couple of days, if this solution works for you, I hope you'll come back and "accept" an answer.